# Have unique values in each while loop iteration

Tags: bash

What I try to achieve, is to define global variables in my script. These variables can be reused in a loop (preferably a while loop..) and with every iteration, the loop should get a new set a variables.

My script (so far):

```
PACKAGE_ASSET_ID=AUTO`date +%s`000001
TITLE_ASSET_ID=AUTO`date +%s`000002
MOVIE_ASSET_ID=AUTO`date +%s`000003
PREVIEW_ASSET_ID=AUTO`date +%s`000004
POSTER_ASSET_ID=AUTO`date +%s`000005

while read name; do
    #DATE=`date +%s`
    #PACKAGE_ASSET_ID="AUTO${DATE}000001"
    #TITLE_ASSET_ID="AUTO${DATE}000002"
    #MOVIE_ASSET_ID="AUTO${DATE}000003"
    #PREVIEW_ASSET_ID="AUTO${DATE}000004"
    #POSTER_ASSET_ID="AUTO${DATE}000005"

    echo $PACKAGE_ASSET_ID
    echo $TITLE_ASSET_ID
    echo $MOVIE_ASSET_ID
    echo $PREVIEW_ASSET_ID
    echo $POSTER_ASSET_ID
done <names.txt
```

Within the file `names.txt`, there are 15 entries. For every entry, the while loop needs to process these sets of variables. Giving me something like

```
AUTO1521884581000001
AUTO1521884581000002
AUTO1521884581000003
AUTO1521884581000004
AUTO1521884581000005

AUTO1521884592000001
AUTO1521884592000002
AUTO1521884592000003
AUTO1521884592000004
AUTO1521884592000005
```

As you can see in the script, I tried putting it into the while loop and with different syntax but regretfully, without success. The results I get are always the same set of variables, for all the 15 entries.

Comment: Does it needs to be a EPOCH date? Could it be some random integer? As in the answer below, it is because, `bash` does _not_ need a more than a second to process your lines resulting in same EPOCH for the all the lines read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you really expect that bash (even bash!) would need more than a second to read one line??  Try adding the nanoseconds.

```
while read name; do
    DATE=$(date +%s%N)
    PACKAGE_ASSET_ID="AUTO${DATE}000001"
    TITLE_ASSET_ID="AUTO${DATE}000002"
    MOVIE_ASSET_ID="AUTO${DATE}000003"
    PREVIEW_ASSET_ID="AUTO${DATE}000004"
    POSTER_ASSET_ID="AUTO${DATE}000005"

    echo $PACKAGE_ASSET_ID
    echo $TITLE_ASSET_ID
    echo $MOVIE_ASSET_ID
    echo $PREVIEW_ASSET_ID
    echo $POSTER_ASSET_ID
done <names.txt
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out myself :D hehehehe
When I added a 'sleep 1', I started to notice some changes ;)
Thanks for reminding!

Comment: Why do we always need to rush things, eh?